# System popup UIAlertView when app accesses map service,can change the message of UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, location, uialertview

My ios app accessing user location,system popup UIAlertView? How can i gain the UIAlertView,and change message ,button?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the message using **`NSLocationUsageDescription`** key in the info.plist.

Add this key to your info.plist and add the message as it's value.

> **NSLocationUsageDescription**
>
> `NSLocationUsageDescription` (String - iOS) describes the reason that
>   the app accesses the user’s location information. When the system
>   prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of
>   the dialog box.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 6.0 and later.

Please check [**InfoPlistKeyReference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

**Or**

use `setPurpose:` method of `CLLocationManager` class.

After initializing it add your message using `setPurpose:`

```
CLLocationManager *locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locManager setPurpose:@"My purpose"];
```